# Why is current density assumed to be uniform in following scenario

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

This was homework question, and i got it right. But i still don't understand why.

Assume that we have some glass rod, which is heated. At the ends of the glass rod potential difference $\Delta V$ is applied. When rod is hot, conductivity varies across the glass rod $\sigma(x)=k/x^2$.

Now, my initial assumption was that electric field $\vec{E}$ will be uniform throughout the rod, and current density will vary (through high conductivity parts of the rod, more current will flow, and for the lower conductivity parts, less current will flow), but i was wrong. I changed my assumptions throughout different tries, and at one try i said "Let's pretend that current density is uniform". This as it turns out, was right assumption.

I couldn't understand why this is true, so I then went on to read from Griffits and Purcell books to see what they say about the topic. It turns out that if current density is changing through the wire ($\nabla\cdot\vec{J}\ne0$), then by continuum equation $\nabla\cdot\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0$ we would arrive that $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\ne0$ which would mean that charge is pilling up somewhere.

After some thinking-time, i realized why this matters. If divergence is positive, then more charge is going out than what is going in, so at one moment, we will run out of charge and current will stop flowing. If divergence is negative, charge is piling up, and at one point there will be enough charge that will create it's own electric field and prevent current from flowing.

Assuming everything i sad is correct (i understood it correctly), why we assume this won't happen? In what situations will this happen?

What's really bothering me is that i don't see a point of current density of we always asume current is uniform.

Comment: Is temperature varying only as a function of position along the length of the rod, or also as a function of distance from the axis of the rod?

Comment: Only along the length of the rod. $x$ is distance from the left edge of the rod.